# Coding Style in Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, coding-style, hashmap

I have been interviewed recently by an eminent silicon valley based firm . I had been asked to  write the code for the following question with O(n) time complexity .

## Question :

Write a function that is given an array of integers. It should return true if
any value appears at least twice in the array, and it should return false if
every element is distinct.

The crux to the question was to use hash maps . I wrote the following code in python :

```
def containsDuplicate(arr):
    hashi={}
    for i in arr:
        try:
            hashi[i]+=1
            return 1
        except KeyError:
            hashi[i]=1
    return 0
```

Overall interview went well and I was able to figure out the best solutions (efficient solutions) of all the questions asked .
Later I got a mail from the company that I was not the best match for the position.When asked the reason for my rejection I was told to work on my coding style .

What does the HR mean when she said that I need to improve on my coding style ? What would be the best way to code the solution to  the problem asked above ?

### Edit :

After reading the code again I believe it was not even necessary to do `hashi[i]+=1` . Just `return 1` was sufficient but I don't think that they rejected me solely due to this minor fault in my coding.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A more concise solution to the problem is:

```
def has_dups(arr):
    return len(set(arr)) != len(arr)
```

On the set creation any dups would be removed so the count would tell us the result. I think the set creation from an iterator is O(n) so it would fulfill that requirement.

Can't promise that is what they are looking for though!

Comment: This would be the correct solution. Notice how much more complicated every other solution offered is. To nit-pick on style, I would fully spell out the words. To me, if you don't do this, you don't understand sets, and you're missing a fundamental tool in the Python toolkit.

Comment: Sneaky but potentially slow as it will always process everything and on an interview I would worry about the lack of documentation.

Comment: I like this solution. But if the goal of the interviewers is to judge about algorithmic capabilities, it might be unwise to rely on existing algorithms from the set class...

Answer (score 4):

Check [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

```
from collections import defaultdict
def is_duplicate(string):
    freq = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
    for c in string:
        freq[c] += 1
    return all(v == 1 for v in freq.values())
```

Comment: Yours is a classical example of not seeing a gorilla. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wf-BqAjZb8M

Answer (score 3):

you would have used "in" instead of try and except.

```
def containsDuplicate(arr):
    hashi={}
    res = 0    
    for i in arr:
        if i not in hashi:
           hashi[i]=1
        else:
            res = 1
            break
    return res
```

Answer (score 2):

It could be that they didn't like the fact that you return 0 or 1 instead of False or True.

Comment: I would also suggest that in an interview supplying code with *no* comments or docstrings and relying on exceptions as a part of your code are both *bad* ideas.  Actually they are bad ideas all the time!

Answer (score 2):

Trying to reverse engineer the interview rejection reason is typically a difficult and often meaningless exercise, so let's reform the question to something more fun and continue to improve on your answer, as you would have if you had been given more time.

**Write a function that is given an array of integers. It should return true if any value appears at least twice in the array, and it should return false if every element is distinct.**

```
def containsDuplicate(arr):
    hashi={}
    for i in arr:
        try:
            hashi[i]+=1
            return 1
        except KeyError:
            hashi[i]=1
    return 0
```

Well, python has a [style guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) that suggests some [spacing](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#whitespace-in-expressions-and-statements), so let's do that. (No one would ever reject someone for this, btw)

Python also uses `True` and `False` more then the C style 0 and 1s for booleans.

```
def containsDuplicate(arr):
    hashi = {}
    for i in arr:
        try:
            return True
        except KeyError:
            hashi[i] = 1
    return False
```

Now, Python officially subscribes to [EAFP](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html) where you use exceptions rather then checking, but some people disagree. If you used checking, we have:

```
def containsDuplicate(arr):
    hashi = {}
    for i in arr:
        if i in hashi:
            return True
        else:
            hashi[i] = True
    return False
```

However, time to get clever. Using sets, we can do:

```
def containsDuplicate(a):
    return len(set(a)) != len(a)
```

Comment: Sidebar: If I were the interviewer and someone gave me the set solution, I'd have fun with them by asking them to prove it's the best solution. They could either: argue it's an O(n) solution based on knowing python internals, or they could tell me that it's the simplest code to maintain. Either one would be fine by me.

Comment: I really don't think using sets are "getting clever". It's the most simple and straightforward approach.

Comment: Agreed. If you're familiar with it, it's straightforward, it's O(n) (assuming python internals work the way I expect them to) and it's easy to read/maintain. However, if you haven't seen it before, it's impossible to come up with on the spot during the interview...

Comment: Which makes it a good interview question, since winging-it isn't really the skill that firms hire for.

Comment: @AaronHall : Although I have used sets before but It didn't seem to strike me at the time of the interview . So I guess besides the application of sets the interviewer might look to the other approach which you are following to write code .

Comment: If you review the basic data model for python http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html, you'll see that Sets are covered right before Mappings and right after sequences. I've seen enough people "forget" about them to know that it's something I would screen for in a hiring situation.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few suggestions.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def contains_duplicates(arr): # PEP recommends not using camel case
    arr_count = defaultdict(lambda: 0) # you should use defaultdict to specify a default value
    for i in arr:
        arr_count[i] += 1
        if arr_count[i] >= 2:
            return True # Python has a boolean type; you shouldn't use 0s and 1s
    return False
```

Comment: You could use `int` instead of `lambda: 0`. Maybe not as obvious.

Comment: @detly: could you elaborate?

Comment: @detly : I didn't know that it was possible to initialize `defaultdict` as zero  without using `lambda` . Thanks for the information .

Comment: @JayanthKoushik - if you just call `int()` it defaults to `0`. So you can pass `int` as the callable thing that `defaultdict` uses for its default values to get `0` for all default values.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your style, you appear to not know that sets are implemented similarly to dicts in Python, and you were unnecessarily complicated in your code. I would have implemented it like Gavin H did.

Also, other elements of style that you should work on (see PEP8):

- single spaces around assignment operators
- use underscores to separate words in names as opposed to camel-case
- learn dict methods (you could have used the `dict.get` method instead of try/except)
- return True or False, not 1 or 0

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of coding style issues with your code, but the one I like least is that it will always process the entire array even if the first two elements are the same.

My take on this would be the following it may not be the shortest but going back later would be better:

```
def has_dups(array):
    """ Return true if there are any duplicates in the array """
    result = False  # Return value
    seen = {}  # Dictionary of values seen
    for val in array:
        if seen.get(val, False):
            result = True  # We have a duplicate
            break  # Return NOW
        else:
            seen[val] = True # Add to seen
     return result
```

In a commercial organisation you are usually looking for code that:

1. Meets the specification - yours did not as it returns 0/1 rather than False/True
2. Meets the standards - yours has several PEP8 issues
3. Is clear and maintainable - yours lacks comments and relies on exceptions to save time in an interview it is a good idea to at least mark where you would comment the code.
4. Is testable - this means one entry and exit and a low complexity

## Edit

The OP has pointed out that their code returns on the first non-exception which I had missed - this emphasises points 3 and 4 above.

Comment: It wouldn't process the entire array if the first 2 elements are same as I have written `return 1` within the `try` statement .

Comment: Missed that which is why multiple return statements are frowned upon in commercial environments.  Other people may have to *maintain* your code.

Comment: I just did!  If it is any help I had an interview where the agency called me back to say - they liked your technical ability and your personality but have turned you down on your dress - what the hell are you wearing? My reply was colours other than black and white everybody there was in black trousers, white shirt, black tie...

Comment: Haha .. I guess for them appearance mattered more than the skills of the individuals .

Answer (score 0):

In this version, I tried to make the early return obvious.

```
def contains_duplicates(arr):
    # returns True if a value of arr occurs more than once
    hashi = {}
    for i in arr:
        if i in hashi:
            return True
        hashi[i] = 1
    return False
```